# SCRIPT10: The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available in IE for my sharepoint site

Tags: internet-explorer, sharepoint-online

[image]

I am getting this error in IE for my sharepoint online site

> SCRIPT10: The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet
>   available.   File: suiteserviceproxyiframe_20c14355.js, Line: 2474,
>   Column: 14406